# Windows 10 utility to replace keyboard repeat with phone-style hold for special characters?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, special-characters

Is there any utility available for Windows 10 that would allow my to replace the default hold-to-repeat-character behavior with a phone-style (Android at least) hold-to-enter-special-character? I can't remember the last time I needed to use the repeat ability vs. needing to enter an accented character (to be fair, my cats are frequent users of the repeat capability, but I expect they'd be just as happy with non-repeated gibberish).

And yes, I know how to enter them and how to find them, it's just really inconvenient and it occurred to me that the repeat feature is probably more of a "we've always done it this way" hold-over from the days of ASCII-only than an actual carefully considered decision.

Comment: Consider whether you might not be better served by changing your keyboard layout to one that supports the accented characters you need, such as the United States-International layout, which allows you to enter the accented characters using e.g., `"` followed by `a` for `ä`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that option also, but it's beyond simply adding accents. In general the phone keyboards provide a much better experience -- obviously being able to directly modify the "key" is a lot of it -- but it seems to me that there is an opportunity here to vastly improve the keyboard experience on a desktop (could use a pop-up display when holding down a key). I just don't know if it's some sort of limitation in Windows that would prevent the creation of such a utility.